# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.combineReducers) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have started with react was experimenting something. but I am continuously getting error sating that  `"Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.combineReducers) is not a function`" here is my demo configuration file

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import App from './containers/App'
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"
import logger from "redux-logger"

import reducer from "./reducers"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())
const store= createStore(reducer,middleware)
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

this index.js of reducers
    import { combineReducers } from "react-redux"
    import users from "./UserReducer"

```
export default combineReducers({
    users,

    }
)
```

User reducer.js

```
export default function reducer(state={users:[]},action){
   // console.log("inside reducer")
   switch(action.type){
       case "FETCH_USERS":{
           console.log("inside reducer",{...state})
           return {...state,users:action.payload}
       }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

combineReducers is provided by the 'redux' package, not 'react-redux'.

So: 
    `import { combineReducers } from 'redux'`
should fix it

Answer (score 1):

How about change this

```
export default combineReducers({
   users,

   }
)
```

To this

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import users from './users'

const someApp = combineReducers({
  users
})

export default someApp
```

And import it in `app.js` or `index.js` where you put your route. Just like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import someApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(someApp)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: how does it make a difference,can you explain

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today but it was working fine before. I was importing `combineReducers from 'redux'`.

I had just changed the separate reducer functions to use `createReducer from '@reduxjs/toolkit'` and after that it broke. Changing the code back still did not work so it could be related to adding in extra types for TypeScript.

Strangely, I was able to fix this by importing `combineReducers from '@reduxjs/toolkit'` instead.